# Is it possible to get the image attachment when a user reply to the bot's question and make the bot embed it

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a command that when someone type `!1`, the bot will send a dm and ask to upload the image then bot will embed that image and send it to a channel.

This is the code I have so far.

```py
@commands.command(name='1')
async def qwe(self, ctx):
    question = '[Upload image]'
    dm = await ctx.author.create_dm()
    channel = self.client.get_channel()

    embed = discord.Embed(
        description=question,
        colour=0xD5A6BD
    )
    await dm.send(embed=embed)
    await self.client.wait_for('message', check=ctx.author)

    url = ctx.message.attachments
    embed = discord.Embed(
        description='image:',
        colour=0xD5A6BD
    )
    embed.set_image(url=url.url)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

However, I get this error when I answer the bot with an upload image:

```py
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError:
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'url'
```

Comment: You can get the image url for from the list of attachments you fetched, `url = url[0].url`

Comment: I tried but discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: This is because you asked for `ctx.message.attachments` which will be an empty list. Indeed, `ctx.message` represents the message where the command was invoked. I added an answer with some changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on the documentation, [`Message.attachments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.attachments) returns a list of [`Attachments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#attachment). You then need to call the [`url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment.url) method on the first element of the list of attachements of the message received, not `ctx.message` (which is the message where the command was invoked).

```py
@commands.command(name='1')
async def qwe(self, ctx):
    question = '[Upload image]'

    # Sending embed
    embed = discord.Embed(description=question, colour=0xD5A6BD)
    await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)

    # Waiting for user input
    def check(message):
        return isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel) and message.author == ctx.author
    message = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

    # Sending image
    embed = discord.Embed(description='image:', colour=0xD5A6BD)
    attachments = message.attachments
    embed.set_image(url=attachments[0].url)

    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Note: you do not need to call the [`create_dm`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.create_dm) method.